# put CLLocationCoordinate2D into CLLocation for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have a method I want to call however when I get back the center of the map, it is in CLLocationCoordinate2D type.

How do I put the results of CLLocationCoordinate2D into CLLocation?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Figured it out.

When mapView changes region, get the Lat and Lon from CLLocationCoordinate2D and create a CLLocation variable with the lat and lon passed in.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){

    var centre = mapView.centerCoordinate as CLLocationCoordinate2D

    var getLat: CLLocationDegrees = centre.latitude
    var getLon: CLLocationDegrees = centre.longitude


    var getMovedMapCenter: CLLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: getLat, longitude: getLon)

    self.lastLocation = getMovedMapCenter
    self.fetchCafesAroundLocation(getMovedMapCenter)

}
```